# Bash-Shell on Android Tablet (Transformer Pad TF701T)

Tags: bash

Is there any way to get a fully working bash shell on Android together with a terminal emulator, that supports a hardware keyboard (German Layout)?

The features I need at least (Terminal Apps, NOT graphical!):

- Bash working with normal .bashrc and scripts (Function Definitions, Aliases...)
- SSH-Client with hostname lookup and the ability to do some SCP stuff
- GIT-Client with hostname lookup and at least push, pull, clone, commit, branch, checkout
- less and nano or at least a vim, when it accepts my german keyboard.

Also would it be nice to have:

- rsync client to do some rsync stuff
- curl and ping
- grep
- some tar and or zip-stuff
- clang-compliler, python interpreter, php interpreter

I already found [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) but it is unusable, because it doesn't support my german keyboard layout of the tablet's hardway keyboard. Also it doesn't support Hostname Lookups.

Also I found [KBOX2](http://kevinboone.net/kbox2.html) but it doesn't have a git-client and uses the zsh shell.

BTW: I am using Android >= 4.2

As a Terminal Emulator, [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) looks good; But is made for Gingerbread.

Just found out, that Kbox2 uses Bash as Shell Interpreter, so I just need Git Packages for it to fulfill my wish.

Answer (score 3):

You may be in luck; I just finished building git for KBOX2. Once I test it and figure out how to run a staged install for redistribution purposes, I can upload it and post a link

EDIT: I've contacted the KBOX2 developer; if the client works hopefully he can package it for download/install to the KBOX2 system.

If you're feeling adventurous (or impatient), you can always build it in KBOX2 yourself; there's a couple of gcc packages available in the downloads section

Comment: great! Will this be a full featured git client?

Comment: It won't support https until I can build libcurl...and that won't happen until I can figure out how to generate a configure script without autoconf.  It *should* do everything else...but since (for now) I only use git to clone repos, I can't say if it does *everything*.

Comment: Well, i need clone, pull, push, checkout and commit - a usual it workflow...

Comment: It *should* do all of that...but I don't want to guarantee it as i haven't tested anything but clone.  I'm a Windows admin by trade; I just started on Android development recently (minus the gcc port I did last year) so I've yet to do much beyond working on ports to the KBOX2 environment, and thus don't have any experience working with repos.  Feel free to post or comment here if something isn;t working and I'll look into it as best I can.

Comment: FYI...the binaries are now available for download here: http://kevinboone.net/kbox2_downloads.html

Comment: Small feedback, first thanks for building these packages, but curl dynamic linking seem broken (could not load library "libcurl.so.5" ...), I don't know how git would be affected as I use it over ssh

Comment: @dvhh: Try copying libcurl.so.5 to the /lib directory in KBOX